# Scale custom marker icon according to zoom level

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to scale a custom marker icon according to the zoom level. My icon should be pretty big while you are zooming very close, but obviously it will be way to big when you zoom far out, so it should automatically scale down.

My latest approach looks like this:

```
var myscale = CGFloat()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    mapView.delegate = self

    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true

    if let mylocation = mapView.myLocation {
        print(mylocation)
        // use for camera position later on
    }
    else {
        // do sth else
    }

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(47.962433, longitude: 12.526859, zoom: 17)
    mapView.camera = camera

    let userImage = UIImage(named: "test_profile_pic.png")!
    let userIcon = UIImage(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(userImage)!, scale: myscale)

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.icon = userIcon
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.962433, 13.526859)
    marker.title = "testMarker"
    marker.snippet = "testSnippet"
    marker.map = mapView

    segmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    segmentedControl.layer.masksToBounds = true

}
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition!) {
    if (mapView.camera.zoom <= 16) {
        myscale = 4.0
    }
    // as soon is this works, some fine tuning in scaling
}
```

With this approach the image is not rescaling to value I set in `didChangeCameraPosition` as its already loaded with scale 1.0. I'm don't really get how I'm able to update the scale of my UIImage. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have to first clear the map and then re-add the markers!